# How to turn dictionary values into lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I keep searching for the answer to this but I can't find it. Forewarning I'm new to Python so apologies in advance for noobiness :D.

Here's the dictionary I have:

```
dict = {'test_key': 'test_value', 'test_key2': 'test_value2'}
```

And here's the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
dict = {'test_key': ['test_value'], 'test_key2': ['test_value2']}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please do not use the built-in function name as your variable name, which will make the built-in `dict` function unavailable.

Comment: We can use tuple unpacking to put *values* of each key into a list. `{k: v for k, *v in dct.items()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the items of the dictionary and assign them lists.

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    dict[ key ] = [ value ]
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I'm facepalming for not realizing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
dict = {key: [values] for key, values in dict.items()}
```

new dict will be:

> {'test_key': ['test_value'], 'test_key2': ['test_value2']}

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict = {'test_key': 'test_value', 'test_key2': 'test_value2'}
    for key, value in dict.items():
        dict[key] = [value]
```

Answer (score 0):

Few ways you can go about this in the order of fastest to slowest implementation:

***Dict comprehension***:

```
{
    k: [v] for k, v in dict.items()
}
```

Simple ***for***:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    dict[k] = [v]
```

Python ***map()***:

```
dict(map(
    lambda x: (x[0], [x[1]]), dict.items()
))
```

**result**:

> {'test_key': ['test_value'], 'test_key2': ['test_value2']}